# How to stop gray bar from appearing when UITextField is focused

Tags: ios, keyboard, uitextfield, ios11

I working on an app that is running on iPad with an external keyboard. I have a textfield at the bottom of screen. I tap in it, and this gray bar appears at the bottom of the screen, covering the textfield. In this case, I don't want it at all. What is it called? Is there some way to disable it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is the virtual keyboard. Every app, even on iPad, even with an external keyboard, must avoid having important interface covered by the virtual keyboard. You should take the usual steps for doing that, responding the keyboard-will-show notification in the usual way.